# Missing or empty input error

Tags: json, perl

I have this problem in my script but I don't have ideas for resolve this !

when I launch the script :

```
boak@boak-LX:~/Documents$ perl dl-sound.pl --url http://soundcloud.com/alexorion/bigger-room-radio-015
Missing or empty input at dl-sound.pl line 100.
```

the script :

```
sub fetch_music_info {
  my ($self, $music_url) = @_;

  $music_url ||= $self->{url};

  my $page = $self->_get_content($music_url);
  my $jsmusic = $1 if ($page =~ m{window.SC.bufferTracks.push\((.*)}i);
  $jsmusic =~ s/;//g if defined($jsmusic);
  $jsmusic =~ s/\)//g if defined($jsmusic);

  my $music_info = JSON::Tiny::decode_json($jsmusic);

  return $music_info;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that  `$jsmusic` is not defined here:

```
my $music_info = JSON::Tiny::decode_json($jsmusic);
```

Change to:

```
my $music_info;
$music_info = JSON::Tiny::decode_json($jsmusic) if defined $jsmusic;
return $music_info;
```

Answer (score 2):

It is unlikely to he the cause of your problem, but you shouldn't make *declarations* conditional. The behaviour is undefined, and it can lead to all sorts of nonsense.

So this

```
my $jsmusic = $1 if $page =~ m{window.SC.bufferTracks.push\((.*)}i;
```

should be

```
my $jsmusic;
$jsmusic = $1 if $page =~ /window\.SC\.bufferTracks\.push\(([^)]*)/i;
```

Note also that I have changed the regex to escape the dots, and to capture only the characters up to the next closing parenthesis. That means the following substitutions shouldn't be necessary if I understand your data properly

---

**Update**

In fact, looking again, the whole purpose of your subroutine is invalidated if the pattern doesn't match, so you should write it more like

```
sub fetch_music_info {
  my ($self, $music_url) = @_;

  $music_url ||= $self->{url};

  my $page = $self->_get_content($music_url);
  if ($page =~ /window\.SC\.bufferTracks\.push\(([^)]*)/i) {
    return JSON::Tiny::decode_json($1);
  }
  else {
    die "Music Info not found";
  }
}
```

Comment: this solution doesn't resolve because the script returns all the time "Music Info not found"

thank's for your reactivity @Borodin

Comment: Well that just means that the regex pattern doesn't appear in the data. There's nothing much else the program can do! Perhaps your regex is wrong. Can you show a sample of the data you're trying to match?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Borodin, but there's a more Perlish way to write this:

```perl
my ($jsmusic) = ($page =~ m{window.SC.bufferTracks.push\((.*)}i);
```

That's because the `=~` operator returns a list of the matchvars (`$1`,`$2`, etc.).

In this case, `$jsmusic` will always be *declared* but it will be undefined if the regexp doesn't match. You need the parentheses around `($jsmusic)` to force the operator to list context.